# Flutter - retain Values after Refresh

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

**I want to learn the best solution for the below mentioned issue.**

I'm Using the GETx library for my flutter project.
I have a home page which shows summarized information of some reports. I can choose to create a report. After saving it (inserts into db), i'll be provided with an ID to display on screen. After refresh, the ID and variables reset. (Controller re-init)

Is it best to use SharedPreference in order to save the ID value? And when user refreshes the page, i can query the DB for the ID and display it on page.

Comment: What db you are saving new report, why dont you save right there?

Comment: @mohammadesmaili im saving in MSSQL db. When i refresh the page, the displayed ID is gone. (but the records are still in db). i need to retain the id for the report page so that i can query from db.

Comment: we cant help you till you share code